# Infinite Plane in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

guys. I'm creating a game in Unity where a car moves on a plane. I want to give the effect of infinite plane.
[Screenshot of Unity project where a car moves on a plane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jc0aW.png)
I want this plane to have the texture absolute to the origin; I want it to act like this Blender material, where Empty is on the origin:
[Blender Material that I want to be made similar in Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDlfK.png)
Where "Empty" is an object that stays at the origin.

I saw that one of the solutions would be to create a kind of texture treadmill with the plane, like this:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class InfiniteScrolling : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float scrollSpeed = 1.0f;
    private Renderer groundRenderer;

    private void Start()
    {
        groundRenderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        float offset = Time.time * scrollSpeed;
        groundRenderer.material.SetTextureOffset("_MainTex", new Vector2(offset, 0));
    }
}
```

But I don't want that, I want the texture to be given based on the origin and that the plane doesn't stand still, but rather that it moves according to the position of the camera. I came up with a solution like this,

```
using UnityEngine;

public class InfinitePlane : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Renderer planeRenderer;
    private Transform cameraTransform;
    private Vector3 initialOffset;

    private void Start()
    {
        planeRenderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        cameraTransform = Camera.main.transform;
        initialOffset = transform.position - cameraTransform.position;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // Updates the position of the plane to follow the camera
        transform.position = cameraTransform.position + initialOffset;

        // Calculates the displacement of the texture based on the position of the camera
        Vector2 textureOffset = new Vector2(cameraTransform.position.x, cameraTransform.position.z);

        // Applies the displacement of the texture
        planeRenderer.material.mainTextureOffset = textureOffset;
    }
}
```

Which also didn't work. Does Unity's mainTextureOffset property have anything to do with the size of the plane? If you know the answer, please reply.

Comment: mainTextureOffset should be in UV coordinates, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

First, to avoid certain bugs/effects like the texture jumping to its position when the game starts you probably will want to use the position of the plane rather than that of the camera for the offset, the offset should be computed with the plane's position rather than the camera's. Additionally, you will need to invert the offset so that it moves in the correct direction.

```
Vector2 textureOffset = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.z);
textureOffset *= -1;
```

Then, if you are using the built in unity plane you will need to divide it by ten because the mesh itself is ten meters wide and the texture is stretched across it. So this line should be added to counteract it.

```
textureOffset /= 10;
```

Furthermore, if you are scaling the plane at all using Unity's transform then you will need to divide the texture offset by that too using this line:

```
 textureOffset /= new Vector2(transform.localScale.x, transform.localScale.z);
```

Lastly, if you are scaling the texture in the material at all, you will need to add this line in order to get the correct result:

```
textureOffset *= planeRenderer.material.mainTextureScale;
```

If you want the code to be a bit cleaner, you could separate it into another method, if you did the final result would look like this:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class InfinitePlane : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Renderer planeRenderer;
    private Transform cameraTransform;
    private Vector3 initialOffset;

    private void Start()
    {
        planeRenderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        cameraTransform = Camera.main.transform;
        initialOffset = transform.position - cameraTransform.position;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // Updates the position of the plane to follow the camera
        transform.position = cameraTransform.position + initialOffset;

        // Applies the displacement of the texture
        planeRenderer.material.mainTextureOffset = GetTextureOffset();
    }

    private Vector2 GetTextureOffset()
    {
        // Calculates the displacement of the texture based on the position of the plane
        Vector2 textureOffset = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.z);

        //Invert the offset so that it counteracts the movement of the plane
        textureOffset *= -1;
 
        //Scale the offset down by ten because the plane mesh is ten meters across
        textureOffset /= 10; 

        //Divide the offset by the local scale of the object so that it moves correctly regardless of scale
        textureOffset /= new Vector2(transform.localScale.x, transform.localScale.z); 

        //Multiply the offset by the texture scaling in the material to counteract any change due to that
        textureOffset *= planeRenderer.material.mainTextureScale; 

        return textureOffset;
    }
}
```

I hope this is helpful in some way, it was an interesting challenge to try to solve.